# Toolbox disappear when adding a layout to a page

Tags: sxa

I  have a template that has some fields and inherits from standard template and page. And on my site, I inserted a page from this template and I added my layout to its presentation details. In my layout, I need to show the fields in my template with some other SXA components such as search result. 
However, when opening the page(based on the template) with experience editor, the SXA toolbox doesn't appear! so I can't add any SXA components.

Is that because the page is based on a template and not a sxa page? Although I made the template inherits from the page.

Comment: Do you still have a placeholder on the page? (might sound silly but I've seen the toolbox disappear when there is no available spot to put any rendering)

Comment: You say you created your own layout - does that mean an actual main layout (cshtml) that is not the sxa one?

Comment: If you are using SXA then do not change and use the SxaLayout.cshtml. When the toolbox is not visible always check browser console for JS errors. In 99% there is something. In your case, it's either a JS error of the fact that you've modified SxaLayout.cshtml.

Comment: As Dawid suggest, please check the browser console for JavaScript conflict and your custom template should be inherited from required templates (check Page template for more details).